# Regex for whitespace delemiter except for [ and ] characters

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, gnu-sed

I consider my self pretty good with Regular Expressions, but this one is appearing to be surprisingly tricky.

I want to trim all whitespace, except the ones between "" and [] characters.

I used this regex `("[^"]*"|\S+)\s+` but did split the **[06/Jan/2021:17:50:09 +0300]** part of my log into two blocks.

Here is my entire log line :

```
[06/Jan/2021:17:50:09 +0300] "" 10.139.3.194 407 "CONNECT clients5.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1" "" "-" "" 4245 75 "" "" "81" ""
```

Result I am getting based on my regex using sed command (replacing whitespace by comma):

```
[06/Jan/2021:17:50:09,+0300],"",10.139.3.194,407,"CONNECT clients5.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1","","-","",4245,75,"","","81",""
```

Finally the result that I want to have :

```
[06/Jan/2021:17:50:09 +0300],"",10.139.3.194,407,"CONNECT clients5.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1","","-","",4245,75,"","","81",""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these samples input looks like logs, so considering they will be always in same format; with this you could try following `awk` code, written and tested in shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v FPAT='[^]]*\\]|"[^"]*"|([0-9]+\\.){3}[0-9]+|[0-9]{2,4}' -v OFS="," '{$1=$1} 1'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

- Simple explanation would be using GNU `awk` here. Which has `FPAT` option available in it.
- Option to set field separators in regex form. It matches things as per mentioned regex in FPAT and makes fields accordingly per line.
- Then setting `OFS`(output field separator) as `,` also for all lines.
- In main program of `awk` resetting line(by resetting 1st field) to apply OFS value to it as per OP's requirement. Which will make sure that commas should come in output as per need only.

***Explanation of regex:***

```
[^]]*\\]               ##Matching everything till ] followed by ] here.
|                      ##OR
"[^"]*"                ##Matching from " till first occurrence of " everything between them including "
|                      ##OR
([0-9]+\\.){3}[0-9]+   ##Matching digits followed by dot 3 times followed by digits
|                      ##OR
[0-9]{2,4}             ##Matching 2 to 4 digits here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match strings between square brackets by adding `\[[^][]*]` as an alternative to Group 1 pattern:

```sh
sed -E 's/(\[[^][]*]|"[^"]*"|\S+)\s+/\1,/g'
```

Now, the POSIX ERE (syntax enabled with the `-E` option) pattern matches

- `(\[[^][]*]|"[^"]*"|\S+)` - Group 1: either

  - `\[[^][]*]` - a `[` char, then zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` char
  - `|`
  - `"[^"]*"` - a `"` char, zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` char
  - `|` - or
  - `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/QmfEOf):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='[06/Jan/2021:17:50:09 +0300] "" 10.139.3.194 407 "CONNECT clients5.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1" "" "-" "" 4245 75 "" "" "81" ""'
sed -E 's/(\[[^][]*]|"[^"]*"|\S+)\s+/\1,/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
[06/Jan/2021:17:50:09 +0300],"",10.139.3.194,407,"CONNECT clients5.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1","","-","",4245,75,"","","81",""
```

Comment: I suggest rewording *Now, the POSIX ERE...* to *Now, the GNU sed ERE...* **or** using the POSIX form of character class. Otherwise a POSIX sed user may be confused why your fine solution does not work for her.

Comment: @dawg I added the `gnu-sed` tag for the question since it is clear OP uses a GNU sed. This context should suffice.